# How do I determine whether my pokemon scales with physical or special damage?

Tags: pokemon-unite

How do I determine whether my pokemon scales with physical or special damage?

It seems like neither type, range/melee, roles, nor colour on moves indicates the scaling of each pokemon's attack.

I have done some testing individually, but I see no pattern nor information that the game provides in an accessible spot - am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update:** This is now accessible in-game since the 1.2.1.3 patch!

Under the "Pokémon" menu, you can check under the Pokémon name in the left side:

[image: Charizard is based on Attack]

[image: Pikachu is based on Sp. Attack]

---

You're right: the game doesn't provide this information in an accessible spot.

As far as I know, the only way to test this is by playing in Practice Mode, and comparing the damage inflicted to the clone with / without some equipped items.

People have already done the hard work for us, so I'll just quote [Serebii](https://www.serebii.net/pokemonunite/pokemon.shtml) here:

| Pokémon | Attack Type |
| --- | --- |
| Venusaur | Special |
| Charizard | Physical |
| Blastoise | Special |
| Pikachu | Special |
| Alolan Ninetales | Special |
| Wigglytuff | Special |
| Machamp | Physical |
| Slowbro | Special |
| Gengar | Special |
| Mr. Mime | Special |
| Snorlax | Physical |
| Blissey | Special |
| Gardevoir | Special |
| Absol | Physical |
| Garchomp | Physical |
| Lucario | Physical |
| Mamoswine | Physical |
| Crustle | Physical |
| Greninja | Physical |
| Talonflame | Physical |
| Sylveon | Special |
| Zeraora | Physical |
| Cinderace | Physical |
| Greedent | Physical |
| Eldegoss | Special |
| Cramorant | Special |

Note that the basic attack of each Pokémon might use a different attack type than listed.